# Keyboard not responding after plugging in USB device

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard

I have MacBook Pro Retina and this issue happens to me very often as I am android developer. Sometime after I plug my Android phone to the USB, my macs keyboard stops responding and only way is to reboot system. I think I managed to brake the keyboard once with a simple pendrive...

I've extracted some logs from the moment the issue happened again. I'mpretty sure if there is anything, there must be in few last ones.

```
14.07.2014 21:30:18,524 Terminal[1927]: CGSCopyDisplayUUID: Invalid display 0x1b400005
14.07.2014 21:30:23,987 Google Chrome[356]: CGSCopyDisplayUUID: Invalid display 0x0b42bfb3
14.07.2014 21:30:23,987 Google Chrome[356]: CGSCopyDisplayUUID: Invalid display 0x0b42bfb4
14.07.2014 21:30:23,987 Google Chrome[356]: CGSCopyDisplayUUID: Invalid display 0x1b400005
14.07.2014 21:30:37,762 Google Chrome[356]: CGSCopyDisplayUUID: Invalid display 0x0b42bfb3
14.07.2014 21:30:37,762 Google Chrome[356]: CGSCopyDisplayUUID: Invalid display 0x0b42bfb4
14.07.2014 21:30:37,762 Google Chrome[356]: CGSCopyDisplayUUID: Invalid display 0x1b400005
14.07.2014 21:37:03,000 kernel[0]: CODE SIGNING: cs_invalid_page(0x1000): p=10814[GoogleSoftwareUp] final status 0x0, allowing (remove VALID) page
14.07.2014 21:37:33,267 com.apple.kextd[12]: Can't create kext cache under / - owner not root.
14.07.2014 21:37:33,276 com.apple.kextd[12]: Can't create kext cache under / - owner not root.
14.07.2014 21:37:34,000 kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::message - kIOUSBMessagePortHasBeenReset.
14.07.2014 21:37:34,000 kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::message - kIOUSBMessagePortHasBeenReset.
14.07.2014 21:37:35,000 kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::_deviceGetReport - DeviceRequest for reportID 0x0 returned with result 0xe000404f - retrying
14.07.2014 21:37:36,273 WindowServer[146]: disable_update_timeout: UI updates were forcibly disabled by application "Android File Transfer" for over 1.00 seconds. Server has re-enabled them.
14.07.2014 21:37:36,591 WindowServer[146]: common_reenable_update: UI updates were finally reenabled by application "Android File Transfer" after 1.32 seconds (server forcibly re-enabled them after 1.00 seconds)
14.07.2014 21:37:40,000 kernel[0]: USBF:    137451.761    AppleUSBEHCI::Found a transaction which hasn't moved in 5000 milliseconds on bus 0x1d, timing out! (Addr: 5, EP: 0)
14.07.2014 21:37:40,000 kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::_deviceSetReport - DeviceRequest for reportID 0xac returned with result 0xe0004051 - retrying
14.07.2014 21:37:40,000 kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::_deviceSetReport - DeviceRequest for reportID 0xac returned with result 0xe000404f - retrying
14.07.2014 21:37:40,000 kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::_deviceSetReport - DeviceRequest for reportID 0xac returned with result 0xe000404f - retrying
14.07.2014 21:37:40,000 kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::_deviceSetReport - DeviceRequest for reportID 0xac returned with result 0xe00002eb - retrying
14.07.2014 21:37:40,000 kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::_deviceSetReport - DeviceRequest returned error 0xe000404f (interface 1, reportID 0xac, payload 2 
14.07.2014 21:37:40,000 kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDebug: _deviceSetReport returned an error in configureDataMode
14.07.2014 21:37:40,000 kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::_deviceSetReport - DeviceRequest returned error 0xe000404f (interface 1, reportID 0xac, payload 2 
14.07.2014 21:37:40,000 kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDebug: _deviceSetReport returned an error in configureDataMode
14.07.2014 21:38:23,105 xpcproxy[10817]: assertion failed: 13E28: xpcproxy + 3438 [D559FC96-E6B1-363A-B850-C7AC9734F210]: 0x2
14.07.2014 21:38:24,763 AddressBookSourceSync[10816]: *** -[IADomainCache init]: IA domains cache couldn't be read.
14.07.2014 21:38:24,764 AddressBookSourceSync[10816]: -[IAPluginManager allAListPlugins] [546] -- *** warning: we're on the slow path.
14.07.2014 21:38:28,635 AddressBookSourceSync[10816]: -[IAPluginManager allAListPlugins] [546] -- *** warning: we're on the slow path.
14.07.2014 21:40:46,207 Console[10822]: setPresentationOptions called with NSApplicationPresentationFullScreen when there is no visible fullscreen window; this call will be ignored.
```

Comment: Could you show us the Console activity at the time stamp when you plug in the Android.

Comment: how do I open such console?

Comment: sorry, go to your Utility folder and open Console app, then click on "all messages" (on the left). You will see lots of text there, just look at the bottom one and plug in the USB. Now copy some 10 lines after you plugged in the USB and paste in here.

Comment: I'll paste it as soon I encounter the issue again

Comment: ok, if you want to alert me, use the @Buscar웃 in your text, otherwise I might not see your update.

Comment: @Buscar웃 I've managed to reproduce issues and paste some logs. I don't see anything spcific in them however. I'm pretty sure that the issue happened after 21:37, but pasting more just in case.